Question on summation involving complex numbers
If $n$ is a positive integer and $\theta_r = (\alpha + 2\pi r)/n$, then
$\qquad\displaystyle\frac{1}{n.\sin\alpha} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{\sin\alpha -x\sin(\alpha-\theta_r)}{x^2-2x\cos\theta_r+1}$
equals to ?
$  I) \quad\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^{2n}-2x^n.\cos\alpha+1}$
$  II) \quad\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^{2n}-x^n+\cos\alpha}$
$  III) \quad\displaystyle \frac{1}{x^{2n}+x^n.\cos\alpha+1}$
$  IV) $ None of these
My Try:
I tried assuming, let $z = e^{i\alpha}$ and then using De-Moivre Theorem we can say that
$\displaystyle z^{1/n} = e^{i\alpha / n} = \cos(\alpha + 2\pi r /n) + i \sin(\alpha + 2\pi r /n)$
where $r$ goes from $0, 1, \dots n-1$
But I am unable to proceed.

try n=1 and n=2

Hint : $x^2-2x cos \theta +1=|x-e^{i \theta}|^2$.

Thank you for the hint, but i am still having trouble getting to the solution and can't think of how to transform the Numerator, could you please provide a bit more guidance

The answer is I).
$f(z)=z^{2n}-2z^n\cos\alpha+1$ has roots exactly at $z=z_r^\pm:=e^{\pm i\theta_r}$ (check!), and we have
$$
\frac1{f(z)}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac1{f'(z_r^+)}\frac1{z-z_r^+}+\frac1{f'(z_r^-)}\frac1{z-z_r^-}\right)
$$
(assuming $\alpha/\pi\notin\mathbb{Z}$, so that the question makes sense). Now simplify the summand, using
$$f'(z)=2nz^{n-1}(z^n-\cos\alpha)\implies f'(z_r^\pm)=\pm 2nie^{\pm i(\alpha-\theta_r)}\sin\alpha.$$
